# How do I update a Lightroom Catalog? (not just the meta data)

Tags: lightroom

How can I refresh a LightRoom catalogue (i.e. re-read all files) to reflect changes I made to existing photographs?

Synchronizing folders works for meta-data but it does NOT pick up changes made to the images themselves.  Importing doesn't work either, duplicate files are ignored there is no option to overwrite ...

What am I missing here?  Surely this must be a common workflow ....

Comment: Just to be clear, you made changes outside of Lightroom?

Comment: yes, I make changes in Photoshop. I think the 'render previews' feature is what I was looking for ....

Answer (score 3):

There are two different things that can go wrong:

1. when you look at your catalog, the small previews of the image are wrong. When you open the image in Develop mode, it's correct however (most likely case)
2. when you look at the catalog, they are wrong AND when you open them in develop, they are wrong.

In case 1, you need to update the previews. Do so in the **library - previews - render previews** menu. Chose "standard previews" for the small windows when you see multiple images in the library, chose 1:1 for the larger 1-image only views in the library window.

In case 2, you have a serious issue. I would most often think that you edited another version of the image, since the develop view is directly read from the file.

Comment: Hi, yes my scenario is 1.  I update the original photo and when I opened in the developer it re-reads the photo from disk - as expected.  I want to force a read of all photos without clicking each and every individual preview picture.  Will try your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisBirmele Good! Try the re-rendering of previews on one of your images and see if that helps.